# Doubt on the definition of ordered topology given in 'Foundations of Topology By C. Wayne Patty'

Tags: general-topology

[image]

If the underlined symbol is as it is, The definition is confusing. Is it 
$\mathscr T$ or $\mathscr S$? Please help me with the definition.

Comment: Is that important?

Comment: Script T $\mathscr T$ and script S $\mathscr S$

Comment: You're right. One of $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T$ is a typo; they should be the same symbol.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question but perhaps worth pointing out: If one adopts the standard convention that the intersection of the empty family of subsets of $\mathcal X$ is $\mathcal X$, then *any* family of subsets of $\mathcal X$ is a subbasis for a topology on $\mathcal X$. So the proof you quote becomes unnecessary, which seems to be a good thing because it doesn't work when the cardinality of $\mathcal X$ is $1$ or $0$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I should use $\mathscr S$ in every place where I underlined. Am I correct?

Comment: that is correct @Mathgeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All marked $\mathcal{T}$ should be $\mathcal{S}$, of course.

`<rant>`
It's too bad so many math-books are submitted as pdf's from Latex sources without the need for human copy editors any more. Huge savings, I know. But earlier all published maths texts went through human eyes during proof reading and type setting and such errors were more rare. 
`</rant>`

Nitpick: note the proodf only works if there **are** at least two points in $X$.
If there is one, so $X = \{p\}$ then $\mathcal{S} = \{\emptyset\}$ and that's a fine subbase (for the discrete = indiscrete topology on $X$) but not in this author's view.